# Find RabbitMQ BROKER_URL

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

this question may be too obvious, but this is the first time I work with Celery and RabbitMQ or anything similar. I need to declare my `BROKER_URL` somewhere, but I don't even know how to find it.. where is it? on the terminal I write `sudo rabbitmq-server` and I can see rabbitmq is running.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for help determining the correct value of `BROKER_URL`, or where to set that value, or both?

Comment: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application

Comment: @KurtRaschke to be honest, I'd like to know both. In django it seems its different.

Comment: Ah, so you're using Celery with Django - that's an important detail that would have been helpful to have in the question.

Comment: Additional answers are available in [this duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957599)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you have followed the Celery [First Steps with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) tutorial. The structure provided by that tutorial (and specifically the line `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')`) in `celery.py` configures Celery to read its settings from the Django configuration.  So, any Celery settings, like `BROKER_URL`, `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`, [or others](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#example-configuration-file) can be configured simply by including them in your Django project's `settings.py` file.

**However, this is probably all irrelevant!**  As the [documentation for the BROKER_URL parameter indicates](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#broker-url), "[the] transport part [of the URL] is the broker implementation to use, and the default is amqp...", and as [the documentation for the underlying messaging library (Kombu)](http://kombu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/connections.html#connection-urls) states, "[a] connection without options will use the default connection settings, which is using the `localhost` host, default port, user name `guest`, password `guest` and virtual host '/'".

What does all of this mean?  In short, it should work out-of-the-box, assuming you are running RabbitMQ on the same computer as your Celery project, and assuming you haven't changed RabbitMQ's settings (i.e. port number, authentication, etc.).  Without a `BROKER_URL` set, Celery will use its default settings, which would have it connect to an AMQP server (i.e. RabbitMQ) on the same computer, using the default `guest` credentials.