# How to find RabbitMQ URL?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Rabbit MQ URL looks like :

```
BROKER_URL: "amqp://user:password@remote.server.com:port//vhost"
```

This is not clear where we can find the URL, login and password of RabbitMQ
when we need to acccess from remote worker (outside of Localhost).

In other way, how to set RabbitMQ IP adress, login and password from Celery / RabbitMQ

Comment: Where do you get this information from? You should check your `celeryconfig.py` and also your `app.py`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19938719/6372139 for more information.

Comment: But, it does not indicate the Ip adress of RabbitMQ server

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create new user for accessing your RabbitMQ broker.
Normally port used is 5672 but you can change it in your configuration file.

So suppose your IP is 1.1.1.1 and you created user test with password test and you want to access vhost "dev" (without quotes) then it will look something like this:

amqp://test:test@1.1.1.1:5672/dev

---

I will recommend to enable RabbitMQ Management Plugin to play around RabbitMQ.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: What /dev means ?  How/Where can we setup ?
What about firewall access ?

Comment: dev is the virtual host(vhost). It can be used to segregate different application to run on same RabbitMQ server with different access policies. The default vhost is "/" (without quotes).

Comment: Firewall Access, you need to enable access to 5672 port. Setup what? the management plugin?

Answer (score 4):

To add to the accepted answer:

- As of 2022, the default username and password are `guest`
- In my experience, ignoring `vhost` is safe while getting started with RabbitMQ
- If using RabbitMQ as part of a Docker Compose setup (e.g. for testing), other containers in the same application should be able to access RabbitMQ via its service name. For example, if the name of the service in `docker-compose.yml` is `rabbitmq`, passing `amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/` should work