# Need help setting BROKER_URL in Airflow's config and Celery Executor

Tags: celery, airflow

## Summary

I'm using Apache-Airflow for the first time. I've gotten the webserver, SequentialExecutor and LocalExecutor to work, but I'm running into issues when using the CeleryExecutor with rabbitmq-server. I currently have two AWS EC2 instances.

### Error

To summarize: My worker cannot connect to the rabbitmq-server on my scheduler node. Whenever I run `airflow worker` on the worker instance, it gives:

```
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.executors.celery_executor:0x7f53a8dce400
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default


[2019-02-15 02:26:23,742: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

### Configuration

I followed all of the directions I could find online. Both instances have the same `airflow.cfg` file, with

```
[core]
executor = CeleryExecutor

[celery]
broker_url = pyamqp://username:password@hostname:port/virtual_host
```

and result_backend pointing at the same MySQL database on RDS that airflow is working off of.

From what I could tell, no matter what, the worker node always tried connecting to a local rabbitmq-server and completely ignored that broker_url in my `airflow.cfg` file.

### What I've Tried

I went spelunking in the source code, and noticed in `celery/app/base.py`, if I error log out the configurations it gets in `_get_config()` when it goes to create a connection, there are actually TWO values in the dictionary returned.

```
BROKER_URL = None
broker_url = pyamqp://username:password@hostname:port/virtual_host
```

and all of the connection logic seems to point at the `BROKER_URL` key.

I tried setting `BROKER_URL` and `CELERY_BROKER_URL` in `airflow.cfg`, but it seems to be case insensitive, and ignores the latter. Just to see if it would work, I modified the `_get_config()` method and hacked in:

```
s['BROKER_URL'] = s['broker_url']
return s
```

And, like I expected, everything started working.

Am I doing something wrong? I'd really rather not use this hack, but I can't understand why it's ignoring the configuration values.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957599/how-to-find-rabbitmq-url

Comment: Do you have a `BROKER_URL` or `AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL` environment variable set?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems like the hostname being passed in the URI is wrong:

- If `rabbitmq-server` and `worker` are in different machines: instead of `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`, the hostname should be the IP address of the `rabbitmq` machine
- If `rabbitmq-server` and `worker` are in the same machine as part of a Docker Compose application (e.g. if you took inspiration from [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml)): the hostname should be the service name associated to the RabbitMQ image in `docker-compose.yml`, e.g. `amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/`